How to implement a library I created using clion on my main project in c++?
So, I turned my project into a library in clion by using the create library option in the menu, but when I build the library, was it not supposed to give me some sort of file so I could include it on my main project's CMake with the target_link_libraries function? All I have is a 'myLib.a' file on the cmake-build-debug folder of my library project. Am I doing something wrong?
I tried creating the new library in multiple ways, but I am not sure of what to expect since every place I go looking for an answer has different methods of getting there, and none worked for me.

mylib.a is the library

Have a look at What is a file with extension .a?. What did you expect? A .so file? That's a dynamic library. .dll? .lib? Those are for Windows.

Create two directories, one for the library and one for the maim application (that uses the library). Use a global CMakeLists.txt file in the parent directory which contains the project command, and two add_subdirectory commands (one for each directory). In the library subdirectory use add_library to create the library. In the application subdirectory use add_executable to create the application, and a target_link_library command to link with the library (using the target name you used in add_library, the actual filename doesn't matter).
